# DDE connection failing for unknown reasons

Tags: qt, dll, connection, dde

I'm trying to create and implement a DDE dll with Qt but as for now I'm being unable to properly connect to a service which I know to be working after testing it with Excel.

The dll connection function is as following:

```
UINT respTemp;

respTemp = DdeInitializeA(&pidInst, NULL, APPCLASS_STANDARD | APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0L);

//handle error messages here
//...

//![]
hszService = DdeCreateStringHandleA(pidInst, (LPCSTR)service.utf16(), CP_WINANSI); //service.toLatin1().toStdString().c_str()
hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandleA(pidInst, (LPCSTR)topic.utf16(), CP_WINANSI); //topic.toLatin1().toStdString().c_str()
hConv = DdeConnect(pidInst, hszService, hszTopic, NULL);

DdeFreeStringHandle(pidInst, hszService);
DdeFreeStringHandle(pidInst, hszTopic);

if (!hConv)
{
    UINT ddeLastError = DdeGetLastError(pidInst);

    switch (ddeLastError)
    {
        case DMLERR_DLL_NOT_INITIALIZED:    return DDEConn_DLLNotInitialized;
        case DMLERR_INVALIDPARAMETER:       return DDEConn_InvalidParameter;
        case DMLERR_NO_CONV_ESTABLISHED:    return DDEConn_NoConvEstablished;

        default:                            return DDEConn_NoConnectionStablished;
    }
}

connStatus = true;

return DDEConn_NoError;
```

The test function is as follows:

```
void MainWindow::on_start_clicked()
{
    const QString application = "profitchart";    //=profitchart|COT!VALE5.ult
    const QString topic = "COT";
    const QString item = "VALE5.ult";

    test = CommDDE::instance();

    CommDDE::DDEConnectionErrorList resp = test->connect(application,topic);

    if (resp == CommDDE::DDEConn_NoError)
    {
        qDebug() << "request RESULT: " << test->request(item);
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "Can't connect to application" << resp;
}
```

Always when I try to connect I get error `DMLERR_NO_CONV_ESTABLISHED` after the call to `DdeConnect`. I couldn't find guidence on what to do when such error occurs. I don't know too much about the details of configuring such functions so I used the default configuration used by a working dll from which I got part of the raw material for this dll. Should I try a different configuration I'm not aware of? Remembering that the call is working on Excel.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem I found the answer: the commented way of writting the service and topic names were the right ways of passing the parameters to `DdeCreateStringHandleA` and `DdeCreateStringHandleA`.